# context of function portTASK_FUNCTION in sourecode of freeRTOS (void)pvParameters

Tags: task, freertos

In tracing source code of task.c for freeRTOS, i see a function named **portTASK_FUNCTION**. its code is as below

```
static portTASK_FUNCTION( prvIdleTask, pvParameters )
{
    /* Stop warnings. */
    ( void ) pvParameters;  //<--what for??

    for( ;; )
    {
        do something
    }
}
```

i don't understand what ***( void ) pvParameters*** means, hope someone could help me, thx

btw, this function's type of args are not declared, why does it can work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code consists of comment:

```
/* Stop warnings. */
```

The optimizer will remove the code you mentioned. But there is unused parameter in function - `pvParameters`. And this code is written to shut up compiler. It does nothing.

Comment: why the unused parameter is put in this macro? what for?

Answer (score 1):

portTASK_FUNCTION is **NOT** a function, its a macro.  If I google it the first link I get is here: http://www.freertos.org/implementing-a-FreeRTOS-task.html - in this case prvIdleTask is the function.  In all but the one obscure case mentioned on the link the portTASK_FUNCTION macro is obsolete (not required) but is used in the main kernel code for portability.

Comment: thx, i got it. it's just a macro and I had found the define in other place